# Make a selection of image transparent in GIMP

Tags: gimp, transparency

I have a picture and I want to have one specific rectangle of this picture appear 50% opaque. The rest remains as it was. How do I do this in GIMP?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Select a rectangular region of the image with the Rectangle Select Tool.
2. Click the Eraser Tool. It looks like a pink eraser.
3. In the Tool Options pane, change the Opacity to 50%.
4. In the Tool Options pane, change the Brush to the brush that looks like a sharp-edged black circle. The name of the brush in the Brush field will change to *2. Hardness 100*.
5. In the Tool Options pane, change the Size to make it large enough to completely overlap the entire selected rectangular region.
6. In the Tool Options pane, change the Dynamics to *Basic Simple*.
7. Click the selected rectangular region once to erase it to 50% opacity with the Eraser Tool.

Comment: Great, it worked! How come I could not find such a clear tutorial on the web? ;-) Thanks!

Comment: I can't always find answers to my own questions about GIMP on the web either. That's why I signed up for Graphic Design Q&A. My first question was successfully answered by a graphics software expert less than two hours after I posted it.

Answer (score 18):

Here is another method to make a selection semi-transparent.

1. Choose *Layer > Transparency > Add Alpha Channel* if not yet done.
2. Select your area.
3. Choose *Select > Float* (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>) for creating a floating selection layer.
4. In the "Layers" tab from the layers menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>) choose the "Floating Selection", leave it *Normal* and set desired opacity.

   [image]

Note that if you need the selected area to be 100% transparent you just have to delete the selected area after step 2. above (*Edit > clear* or <kbd>Del</kbd>. No need to create a floating selection.